# url rewrite, suggest for a simple rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url could be like this one

```
mysite.com/subfolder?page=identifier&other=lorem&parameter=ipsum&to=dolor&retrive=amet...
```

How to have a sef url like that

```
mysite.com/subfolder/page/identifier/?other=lorem&parameter=ipsum&to=dolor&retrive=amet...
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic you are wanting to get from the first URL to the second?  Where did "lang=eng" go, for example?

Comment: edited: a fixed var page and more params (not url friendly)

Comment: if anything the second URL seems less SEF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert with URL rewriting, but maybe something like :

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/page/(.*)/?other=(.*)&parameter=(.*)&to=(.*)$ /subfolder?page=$1&other=$2&parameter=$3&to=$4
```

Comment: the question is not about a fixed number of params. Thank you anyway